# WebXR and WebRTC don't work simultaneously

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, webrtc, simplewebrtc, webxr

I am new to WebXR. I was trying to use webRTC with WebXR. The user will first enter into AR session and then create a WebRTC peer connection but ice candidates are not generated in Chrome for Android of the user is in AR session. As soon as the user gets out of AR session, ice candidates are transferred. Is this a bug in Chrome??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Hardware related. Some devices allow the use of both Front and back camera simultaneously. In such devices, the code worked properly. In other devices, both front and back camera cannot be accessed simultaneously. Hence, code does not work in these devices. Also, the WebXR Device API does not allow access to camera feed at the moment, however it is a proposed feature.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tried it myself. But you can in theory use the canvas captureStream API to stream webXR canvas.
Can you post your code here. You might want to tweak how you pass stream to the webrtc connection.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to use canvas.captureStream() because WebXR doesn't render to the canvas directly.
I am also looking for a way to stream a webXR-Session via WebRTC. So I would be highly interested in your solution shivamag00!
Hope to hear from you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).